# How get RU-RU element in json file

Tags: python, json

I have json file. I need get LocalizedNames Ru-RU on python.
This my python class:

```
import json

from Item import Item

class FileJsonParser:

    @staticmethod
    def parse():
        listItems = list()
        with open('items.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            counter = 0
            for item in data:
                newItem = Item(item['UniqueName'],item['LocalizedNames'], item['LocalizedDescriptions'])
                listItems.insert(counter, newItem)
                counter += 1
        return listItems
```

```
{
   "LocalizationNameVariable": "@ITEMS_T1_FARM_CARROT_SEED",  
   "LocalizationDescriptionVariable": "@ITEMS_T1_FARM_CARROT_SEED_DESC", 
   "LocalizedNames": {
     "EN-US": "Carrot Seeds",
     "DE-DE": "Möhrensamen",
     "FR-FR": "Graines de carotte",
     "RU-RU": "Семена моркови",
     "PL-PL": "Nasiona Marchwi",
     "ES-ES": "Semillas de zanahoria",
     "PT-BR": "Sementes de Cenoura",
     "IT-IT": "Semi di carota",
     "ZH-CN": "胡萝卜种子",
     "KO-KR": "당근 씨앗",
     "JA-JP": "ニンジンの種子",
     "ZH-TW": "胡蘿蔔種子",
     "ID-ID": "Benih Wortel"   
},
```

I try get LocalizedNames RU-RU such method but it doesn't work:
item['LocalizedNames']['RU-RU']

Comment: Have a good think about exactly what `for item in data` is doing, then think about *why* you believe your proposed indexing will (not) work.

Answer (score 0):

It answer on my question:

```
 for i, item in enumerate(data):
    res = item['LocalizedNames']['RU-RU']
```